# Google Analytics like region map

Tags: google-maps, google-visualization

I'm researching Google's Geo Chart:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

I'm trying to get the map to draw the boundaries by a region rather than a country, something similar to what google analytics provides, for example:

USA:
[image: USA States/Regions on google analytics]

OR India:
[image: India Regions on google analytics]

The following code is one of the ways I've tried to no avail:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Region'],
    ['California'],
    ['Utah']
    ['Scotland']
    ['England']
  ]);

  var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
      document.getElementById('visualization'));
  geochart.draw(data, {width: 556, height: 347});
}
```

​Note that I want to do this in chart's Regions mode rather than Markers mode.

Is this achievable with Geo Chart? and if not does google provide any api to mimic the region delimited map rendering it uses for Analytics?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Blexy Is it possible to do this for the districts in a state of India?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `resolution` and `region` options:

```
geochart.draw(data, {
    width: 556,
    height: 347,
    resolution: 'provinces',
    region: 'US'
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this for the districts in a state of India?

Comment: @Sumit, last I knew, resolutions below the state or province level are generally not supported in GeoCharts. The only exception to that rule that I know of is for metro codes in the US. It is possible that there exist more detailed maps of India, but if there are, they aren't documented. You could try to use the [ISO_3166-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2)
 region code for the districts, and maybe it would work? See the GeoMap [documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#regions-mode-format) for details.

Comment: @Sumit, if that doesn't work, and you are dedicated enough to create your own map, there is a [thread on the Visualization API discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/KVGu--jjUpk/discussion) that talks about how to create your own maps.

Comment: ISO region codes for districts in India does not work, it says `requested map does not exist`. I am trying to find state-wise SVG maps which have districts annotated in the `id` attribute of the `path` tag, please let me know if there is any better alternative.